# i have problem with save data laravel 8 have

Tags: php, laravel

i make this query

public function  scopeSelection($query){

```
    return $query -> select('abbr', 'name', 'direction', 'active');
}
```

and this function for save data but nothing save in my database
public function store(LanguageRequest $request)
{

```
    try {

        Language::created($request->except(['_token']));
        return redirect()->route('admin.languages')->with(['success' => 'success']);
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        return redirect()->route('admin.languages')->with(['error' => 'error']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert a new record into the database, you should instantiate a new model instance and set attributes on the model. Then, call the save method on the model instance:

```
$language = new Language();
$language->iso = $request->iso;
$language->save();
```

In this example, we assign the `iso` field from the incoming HTTP request to the `iso` attribute of the `App\Models\Language` model instance. When we call the `save` method, a record will be inserted into the database. The model's `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps will automatically be set when the save method is called, so there is no need to set them manually.

Alternatively, you may use the **create** method (not created) to "save" a new model using a single PHP statement. The inserted model instance will be returned to you by the `create` method:

```
use App\Models\Language;

$language= Language::create([
    'iso' => 'enGB',
]);
```

However, before using the `create` method, you will need to specify either a `fillable` or `guarded` property on your model class. These properties are required because all Eloquent models are protected against mass assignment vulnerabilities by default. To learn more about mass assignment, please consult the [mass assignment documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment).